# How to refactor long if/return statements in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I frequently encounter a complex pile of `if` statements, what is the Ruby way to clean this up?

(In this service object example, a foo has many bars. This is for transferring a bar to a different foo.)

```
class BarManager
  include FancyErrorLogger

  def self.transfer(bar, new_foo)

    # Is a move needed? Is this line superfluous and a premature optimisation?
    return true if bar.foo_id == new_foo.id

    # Checks that bar can be moved to new_foo. Many more elsifs in practice, needs refactoring. These examples demonstrate the potential complexity of each step, preventing the use of overly simplistic solutions such as seen here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14080/avoiding-a-lot-of-ifs-in-ruby
    if bar.dependency == :do_not_move_me or bar.some_condition == false
      bar.errors.add( :transfer, "This is the bar that can't be moved, it is on street corners moping and singing")
      return false
    elsif new_foo.want_more_bars == false
      bar.errors.add( :transfer, "\"We don't take kindly to your type, bar\" - #{new_foo.name}")
      return false
    elsif ((bar.baz.optional_external_nightmare_status != :unused) || (new_foo.bars.inject(false){|result, element| result = result || element.baz.optional_external_nightmare_status != :unused}))
      bar.errors.add( :transfer, "I have some baz news for you...")
      return false
    elsif bar.yet_another_failure_reason_there_are_many
      bar.errors.add( :transfer, "There are many ways for this to fail, this if statement is somewhat short")
      return false
    elsif bar.stubborn?
      bar.lure_with_carrot!
      if bar.munching?
        bar.errors.add ( :transfer, "eh, what's up doc" )
        return false
      elsif !bar.following?
        bar.errors.add ( :transfer, "Your carrot is too small and inadequate. No jokes please" )
        return false
      end
    end

    # We made it through the gauntlet, now for the transfer
    cache_old_foo_id = bar.foo_id # we might need this
    bar.foo_id = new_foo.id
    bar.save!

    # If we are using Rails counter caching:
    Foo.increment_counter(:bars_count, new_foo.id)
    Foo.decrement_counter(:bars_count, cache_old_foo_id) # we DID need it

    return true

  rescue Exception => e
    fancy_error_log e
    false
  end

end
```

Comment: Always a good read: 
http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/

Comment: BarManager looks like it could be approaching a [God Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object). I am wary of xxxManager objects in general, it's too easy to give them too many responsibilities.

Comment: Do you "encounter" them, or do you "create" them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1 is to remove duplication from that long `if` statement. `if` returns a value (and returns nil if no `if`/`elsif` matches), so you can do

```
error =
  if bar.dependency == :do_not_move_me or bar.some_condition == false
    "This is the bar that can't be moved, it is on street corners moping and singing"
  elsif new_foo.want_more_bars == false
    "\"We don't take kindly to your type, bar\" - #{new_foo.name}")
  elsif ((bar.baz.optional_external_nightmare_status != :unused) || (new_foo.bars.inject(false){|result, element| result = result || element.baz.optional_external_nightmare_status != :unused})
    "I have some baz news for you..."
  elsif bar.yet_another_failure_reason_there_are_many
    "There are many ways for this to fail, this if statement is somewhat short"
  elsif bar.stubborn?
    bar.lure_with_carrot!
    if bar.munching?
      "eh, what's up doc"
    elsif !bar.following?
      "Your carrot is too small and inadequate. No jokes please"
    end
  end
if error
  bar.errors.add :transfer, error
  return false
end
```

Step 2 is to extract the conditions into methods with understandable names, which is a good idea in any case. Move everything in each condition into its method, even `!` operators, and give every method the same parameter list. We'll see why in a moment.

```
error =
  if bar.unmovable? new_foo
    "This is the bar that can't be moved, it is on street corners moping and singing"
  elsif bar.unwanted? new_foo
    "\"We don't take kindly to your type, bar\" - #{new_foo.name}")
  elsif bar.has_bad_news? new_foo
    "I have some baz news for you..."
  elsif bar.will_fail_for_yet_another_reason? new_foo
    "There are many ways for this to fail, this if statement is somewhat short"
  elsif bar.lure_with_carrot? new_foo # if you don't like the side effects, lure it before the if
    "eh, what's up doc"
  elsif bar.uninterested_in_carrot? new_foo
    "Your carrot is too small and inadequate. No jokes please"
  end
# use error as above
```

Step 3 is to remove duplication again:

```
checks = {
  unmovable?: "This is the bar that can't be moved, it is on street corners moping and singing",
  unwanted?: "\"We don't take kindly to your type, bar\" - #{new_foo.name}"),
  has_bad_news?: "I have some baz news for you...",
  will_fail_for_yet_another_reason?: "There are many ways for this to fail, this if statement is somewhat short",
  lure_with_carrot?: "eh, what's up doc",
  uninterested_in_carrot?: "Your carrot is too small and inadequate. No jokes please"
}
method_name, error = checks.find { |method_name, _| bar.send :method_name, new_foo }
# use error as above
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a special exception type:

```
begin 
  fail BarTransferError, "This is the bar that can't be moved, it is on street corners moping and singing" if bar.dependency == :do_not_move_me or bar.some_condition == false
  fail BarTransferError, "\"We don't take kindly to your type, bar\" - #{new_foo.name}" if new_foo.want_more_bars == false
  fail BarTransferError, "I have some baz news for you..." if ((bar.baz.optional_external_nightmare_status != :unused) || (new_foo.bars.inject(false){|result, element| result = result || element.baz.optional_external_nightmare_status != :unused}))
  fail BarTransferError, "There are many ways for this to fail BarTransferError,, this if statement is somewhat short" if bar.yet_another_fail BarTransferError,ure_reason_there_are_many

  if bar.stubborn?
    bar.lure_with_carrot!
    fail BarTransferError, "eh, what's up doc" if bar.munching?
    fail BarTransferError, "Your carrot is too small and inadequate. No jokes please" unless bar.following?
  end
rescue BarTransferError => e
  bar.errors.add(:transfer, e.message)
  return false
end
```

Comment: The problem with doing this is it puts the conditionals for each line WAY to the right, where they're not very visible. They control the flow of the code, so they need to be where they're easily seen for maintenance.